# How can I add an epub to the libarary with SkyEPub SDK?

Tags: android, epub

I am trying to add an epub file called test.epub to my SkyEPub test app. I'm not sure what method to use that will add the epub to the library.

```
public void libraryButtonClick() {
String targetDir = new String(SkySetting.getStorageDirectory() + "/books/test.epub");
showToast("targetDir "+targetDir);
//ls.startDownload(targetDir,"","","");
}
```

**UPDATE**
I tried using this solution
[android epub library, skyepub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360383/android-epub-library-skyepub)

With a few modifications

```
public void unzipBook2(String fileName) {

    String targetDir = new String(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/books/" + fileName);
    targetDir = SkyUtility.removeExtention(targetDir);

    String filePath = new String(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/books");
    Unzip unzip = new Unzip(fileName, filePath, targetDir);
    unzip.addObserver(new UnzipHandler2());
    unzip.unzip();      
}

class UnzipHandler2 implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        //Unzip completed
        (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            }
        },500);     
    }       
}
```

but I end up getting these errors

```
01-19 21:14:00.650: D/UnZip(2370): unzipping test.zip to /data/data/com.skytree.epubtest/files/books/test
01-19 21:14:00.653: E/UnZip(2370): Error while extracting file /data/data/com.skytree.epubtest/files/books/test.zip
01-19 21:14:00.653: E/UnZip(2370): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.skytree.epubtest/files/books/test.zip: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-19 21:14:00.653: E/UnZip(2370):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the tutorial provided by SkyEpub references a Java method

```
private void installSamples()
```

There seems to have been a major code revision at v3.8.0. Older version of the android sample have this `installSamples` method and should provide a good reference for how to install epubs using this SDK.

Older versions can be downloaded from a Dropbox account. There is a link to "SkyEpub Old Releases" http://skyepub.net/downloads/